# Cannot find symbol variable dkey_0

Tags: java, encryption

So my question is when I go to compile my TestCaesarCipherTwo class an error stating `cannot find symbol  variable dkey_0` appears. I have dkey_0 in another class as well as in TestCaesarCipherTwo. I feel like I've mixed up the code somewhere, with so many methods being called at once. The dkey_0 which causes the error is in this line: `System.out.println("Keys found: " + bct.dkey_0 + ", " + bct.dkey_1 + "\n" + broken);`.

Could someone please take a look at where I've gone wrong?

Here's the code where the error happens:

```
import edu.duke.*;
/**
 * Write a description of TestCaesarCipherTwo here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class TestCaesarCipherTwo {
    /**
     * Calls two key encryption and decryption functions 
     * with test keys as defined in the exercise
     */
    public void simpleTests()
    {
        int key1 = 17;
        int key2 = 3;
        FileResource fr = new FileResource();
        String message = fr.asString();
        CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(key1, key2);
        String encrypted = cctk.encrypt(message);
        System.out.println(encrypted);

        String decrypted = cctk.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println(decrypted);

        BreakCaesarTwo bct = new BreakCaesarTwo();
        String broken = bct.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Keys found: " + bct.dkey_0 + ", " + bct.dkey_1 + "\n" + broken);    
  }

  /**
     * Selects and breaks any two key encrypted file. 
     * (So long as the most frequent letter is 'e')
     */
    public void simplebreaker()
    {
        FileResource fr = new FileResource();
        String encrypted = fr.asString();
        BreakCaesarTwo bct = new BreakCaesarTwo();
        String broken = bct.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Keys found: " + bct.dkey1 + ", " + bct.dkey2 + "\n" + broken);
    }
  public String breakCaesarTwo(String input) {
    String in_0 = halfOfString(input, 0);
    String in_1 = halfOfString(input, 1);
    // Find first key
    // Determine character frequencies in ciphertext
    int[] freqs_0 = countOccurrencesOfLetters(in_0);
    // Get the most common character
    int freqDex_0 = maxIndex(freqs_0);
    // Calculate key such that 'E' would be mapped to the most common ciphertext character
    // since 'E' is expected to be the most common plaintext character
    int dkey_0 = freqDex_0 - 4;
    // Make sure our key is non-negative
    if (dkey_0 < 0) {
        dkey_0 = dkey_0+26;
    }
    // Find second key
    int[] freqs_1 = countOccurrencesOfLetters(in_1);
    int freqDex_1 = maxIndex(freqs_1);
    int dkey_1 = freqDex_1 - 4;
    if (freqDex_1 < 4) {
        dkey_1 = dkey_1+26;
    }

}
}
```

And here's the code from where I'm trying to call BreakCaesarTwo (bct) for the line `System.out.println("Keys found: " + bct.dkey_0 + ", " + bct.dkey_1 + "\n" + broken);`:

```
 public class BreakCaesarTwo{
    private String alphabetLower;
    private String alphabetUpper;
    private String shiftedAlphabetLower1;
    private String shiftedAlphabetUpper1;
    private String shiftedAlphabetLower2;
    private String shiftedAlphabetUpper2;
    private int mainKey1;
    private int mainKey2;


    public String encrypt(String input) {
        StringBuilder encryptedInput = new StringBuilder(input);
        OOCaesarCipher oocc1 = new OOCaesarCipher(mainKey1);
        OOCaesarCipher oocc2 = new OOCaesarCipher(mainKey2);

        for (int index=0; index < input.length(); index++) {
            if (index % 2 == 0 || index == 0) {
                encryptedInput.replace(index,index+1,oocc1.encrypt(input.substring(index,index+1)));
            }
            else {
                encryptedInput.replace(index,index+1,oocc2.encrypt(input.substring(index,index+1)));
            }
        }
        return encryptedInput.toString();
   }
      public String halfOfString(String message, int start) {
        StringBuilder halfString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index=start;index < message.length();index += 2) {
            halfString.append(message.charAt(index));
        }
        return halfString.toString();

  }
   public int[] countOccurrencesOfLetters(String message) {
        //snippet from lecture
        String alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int[] counts = new int[26];
        for (int k=0; k < message.length(); k++) {
            char ch = Character.toLowerCase(message.charAt(k));
            int dex = alph.indexOf(ch);
            if (dex != -1) {
                counts[dex] += 1;
            }
        }
        return counts;
  }
   public int maxIndex(int[] values) {
        int maxDex = 0;
        for (int k=0; k < values.length; k++) {
            if (values[k] > values[maxDex]) {
                maxDex = k;
            }
        }
        return maxDex;
  }
     public String breakCaesarTwo(String input) {
    String in_0 = halfOfString(input, 0);
    String in_1 = halfOfString(input, 1);
    // Find first key
    // Determine character frequencies in ciphertext
    int[] freqs_0 = countOccurrencesOfLetters(in_0);
    // Get the most common character
    int freqDex_0 = maxIndex(freqs_0);
    // Calculate key such that 'E' would be mapped to the most common ciphertext character
    // since 'E' is expected to be the most common plaintext character
    int dkey_0 = freqDex_0 - 4;
    // Make sure our key is non-negative
    if (dkey_0 < 0) {
        dkey_0 = dkey_0+26;
    }
    // Find second key
    int[] freqs_1 = countOccurrencesOfLetters(in_1);
    int freqDex_1 = maxIndex(freqs_1);
    int dkey_1 = freqDex_1 - 4;
    if (freqDex_1 < 4) {
        dkey_1 = dkey_1+26;
    }

    CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(dkey_0, dkey_1);
    return cctk.decrypt(input);
  }
  public String decrypt(String input) {
      CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk= new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(26 - mainKey1, 26 - mainKey2); 
      String decrypted = cctk.encrypt(input); 
      return decrypted;

     }
}
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. dkey_0 is already included in both classes (BreakCaesarTwo  and TestCaesarCipherTwo). I was trying to add the void methods SimpleTests and SimpleBreaker, when I got this error.
As a side note: The purpose of this program is to encrypt, decrypt, and print out the message decrypted along with the two keys which alternatively decrypt the message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `dkey_0` variable is a local variable. In order to access this variable from `TestCaesarCipherTwo` you must make it an instance variable of the `BreakCaesarTwo` class. The same holds for the rest of the variables.

Comment: Should I add it just below where I declare the TestCaesarCipherTwo class?

Comment: You must add this variable `dkey_0` just like you have `mainKey1` in the `BreakCaesarTwo` class. Of course, encapsulate this variable.

Comment: Should I have `dkey_0` initialized in the BreakCaesarTwo or in the TestCaesarCipherTwo? Because having it in the BreakCaesarTwo doesn't help.

Comment: Do you access this instance variable directly or by means of `getter` ?

Comment: Directly. I'm not using any `getter` method.

Comment: That is why I told you to encapsulate it. Anyway, are you sure you want to print `dkey_0` variable? You don't even call this `breakCaesarTwo` method anywhere.

Comment: Are you saying I can use dkey_0 without calling bct such as in `"Keys found: " + bct.dkey_0 + ", " + bct.dkey_1 + "\n" + broken`?

Comment: Am I? Forget it, I give up.